# One click focus to the desktop with Gnome Shell 3.4.2

Tags: gnome, focus

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with **Gnome Shell 3.4.2**.
I have restored desktop icons with Gnome Tweak Tool and now I want to know if there is an one click (on blank space) option from "Activities" overview to **focus** to the desktop without the need to switch workspace from the panel on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extension: [Show Desktop from Overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/496/show-desktop-from-overview/):

> A Click on an empty space in the window overview shows the desktop. That means: It minimizes all windows on the current workspace.

To install it, open the link in Firefox while GNOME Shell is active. There should be an On/Off slider next to the name of the extension:

[image]